# Magento: local.xml doesn't show block

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

So I have empty package where is stored local.xml

(Paths I don't describe here, all caches disabled, error logs turned on).

I've added static block in admin panel. It is named "two_level_links".

Then I added code to local.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <remove name="top.links"/>
            <block type="cms/block" name="topTwoLevelLinks">
                <action method="setBlockId">
                    <block_id>two_level_links</block_id>
                </action>
           </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

In the header phtml file call it:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topTwoLevelLinks') ?>
```

**top.links** disappeared but topTwoLevelLinks *didn't appear*.

Then I looked at Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update and set a var_dump for getFileLayoutUpdatesXml [$layoutXml]. The source has my block.

Cannot understand what I should do next. How to debug it? Or where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To make life easier: `<remove />` and `<reference />` both operate in the context of the layout object, so there's no need to nest calls - you can just refer to the block directly underneath a layout update handle. Also, version attribute for `<layout />` is not parsed, so it's ok to leave that off as well.

Comment: By the way, this syntax looks correct. Is the static block set to be available for the store scope in which you are calling it?

Comment: It is available for all views. Could you describe your vision on update in more detail please?

Answer (score 1):

everything looks fine, but let me suggest you to check next things:

1. Check in admin panel if your block is enabled.
2. If you have more than one store view, please check if you your block is associated to your current store view, that you see on the frontend
3. Check in which folder header.phtml file is placed. For example if you changed the header.phtml from your base theme folder "app/design/frontend/base/default", Magento never will know about it if you also have header.phtml in "app/design/frontend/custom_package/custom_theme/" ... if it is not clear enough, please read: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy

Comment: All points are ok. I've checked it. But I tried to create another custom theme and copied to this folder all my default theme. Now it works. I'm confused a bit.

Comment: @Anthony Are you sure, that you didn't add <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topTwoLevelLinks') ?> to header.phtml of your default theme in app/design/frontend/base/default ? Read carefully the article, that I suggested above and take a look at sections:  "The Design Fall-Back Hierarchy"

Comment: Yes, I do. Over more if I change there smth then it changed on the screen after reload. But <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topTwoLevelLinks') ?> doesn't appear.